# How to find client's location vi IP Address

Tags: ip

how can I find "client location" via client ip like this http://www.whatismyip.com/ip-address-lookup/ . I'm using Java to develop server

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this:http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-find-location-using-ip-address/

GeoLite Database